# Network Error 0x2ee4 in IE10 for angular directives

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api

Directive html files do not load in IE 10 and prompt with network error 0x2ee4. Issue occurs on VMs only.
Behavior is random. Few files load sometimes.
Error is somewhat similar to 
https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/852785/ie10-network-error-0x2ee4-https-proxy-ajax

I need a fix in IE10. Any help.

[Screenshot of root](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U4ikB.png)

Comment: Could you explain more you app architecture? Where is folders, how you a trying to load the files, your VM structure, are u using apache inside that VM?

Comment: just added screen shot as well. Vm running with windows server.

Comment: [Here](https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/852785/ie10-network-error-0x2ee4-https-proxy-ajax) are answers given.